# Query for searching a particular value in multiple arrays and also get the result that which array fields contains those values in mongo db

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to search the red marked value and get name of all array fields which are containing this value. For example in this screenshot I want to search with `_id` and the value viz `ObjectId(5e23d52622948b7c28013def)` and the result should be the "followers" because it contains my required search please help me.

[here is the screenshot of the documents of my social connections. I want to get the name of the array fields who are containing the marked value.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDfLk.png)

Comment: Please share the sample data & the response sample that you are expecting from this query

Comment: I have attached photo of my data and I want to make a query like, db.social.find({_id,"which of the fields contains this value ""_id"});              please please see the attached photo. I want to get the name of the array fields which contains my searched value.

Comment: You want list of documents which contains specified id in either followers / following array, right ?

Comment: I want the name of these followers or following array if they contains my searched id.Like if i search some id and if the followers or following array contains those id then return true as followers:true or give result by something else. But i just want to know whether these array(followers or following) contains my searched id or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your query like this

```
// follower
db.social.findOne({
    '_id':user_id,
    'social_connections.follow.followers':search_id
})

// following
db.social.findOne({
    '_id':user_id,
    'social_connections.follow.following':search_id
})
```

Here `search_id` is the variable id you want to search in database, and `user_id` is the document in which you want to search

If the result is a document, your answer is true, if its null/undefined your answer is false

Comment: and where do i put the _id of the document in which i want to search

Comment: What if same 'search_id' is in both follow and followers how would i know that it is in follow and followers?

Comment: You can write 2 seperate querries without '$or' block for the same